# How to return multiple values in an AJAX call?

Tags: php, ajax

Let's say I would like to output two different types of data to two of my divs, `#count_boys` and `#count_girls`. For the sake of clarifying my goal I have added `data.boys` and `data.girls` to my html call. Not that it works, but it hopefully clarifies what I am trying to achieve.

Let's assume that I have boys and girls in my database as table columns in my MySQL DB.

```
function countlist() {
    var generic;
    $.ajax({
        method: "GET",
        url: "ajaxcalls/numbercall.php?",
        data: generic,
        success: function(data) {
            //general contractors//
            $('#count_boys').html(data.boys);
            $('#count_girls').html(data.girls);
        } 
    });
}
```

Now, my **numbercall.php** looks something like this:

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'coolkidsclub');
$query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM members");

$num = mysqli_num_rows($query);
echo "$num";
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

I understand that using a PHP encode would be the way to go about this. But I'm not entirely sure how to go about using it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To return data to a javascript AJAX call use JSON encoded data.

All you do is create a PHP data structure, array or object and then use `json_encode()` to convert it to a JSON String for sending back to the javascript.

```
<?php

$con = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'coolkidsclub');
$query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT count(*) as cnt
                             FROM members 
                             WHERE gender = 'boys'");

$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);
$boys = $row['cnt'];

$query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT count(*) as cnt
                             FROM members 
                             WHERE gender = 'girls'");

$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);
$girls = $row['cnt'];

echo json_encode( array('boys'=>$boys, 'girls'=>$girls) );
?>
```

Now change the javascript to tell it that JSON will be returned and it will automatically be converted from a JSON String to a javascript object

```
function countlist(){
    var generic;
    $.ajax({
        method: "GET",
        url: "ajaxcalls/numbercall.php?",
        data: generic,
        dateType: 'JSON',           // added parameter
        success: function(data){
            //general contractors//
            $('#count_boys').html(data.boys);
            $('#count_girls').html(data.girls);
        } 
    });
}
```

Comment: Riggs is correct- you cannot return multiple "values" but you can return a single value in an array.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I only had one more question regarding this. Each `$query` makes its own mysqli connection. Would this pose a problem if I pilled on more connections? Like, instead of boys and girls, I output every ethnicity.

Comment: No you can make the returned JSON data structure as complex as you like